# How to Prove a Subquery is Necessary?

Tags: sql, subquery, relational-database

I have been told that this question cannot be answered with a standard `SELECT FROM WHERE` query in an RDBS, but instead, I must use a subquery, i.e., a statement of the sort
`SELECT FROM WHERE (SELECT...)` instead. I would appreciate an explanation or a reference to this effect, or, a disproof if it applies.

The beef: I have a table containing information about, among others, available rental properties and rental price per property. I want to obtain as output, the set of properties with the lowest rent in the listing. A way of  obtaining an answer is:

```
SELECT propertyId, rentalprice FROM table 
WHERE rentalprice = (SELECT MIN(rentalprice) FROM table)
```

This answers the question, but is there a good argument for why this question cannot be answered by a single query, i.e., without the use of subqueries? I understand that `min(rentalprice)` selects a specific (set of) row value(s) with the lowest rental price and then `PropertyId` in output consists of the set of propertyIds with min price, but I cannot think of a good argument for why this question cannot be answered by a single query. I guess it is ultimately an issue of what can and cannot be done within Relational Algebra?
Thanks.

Comment: My thought process:
1. you want the minimum price. Ok, select min(rentalprice)
2. you also want to know the propertyId. But when you add that to the select statement, it complains and asks you to group by any column not used in an aggregate function. However, grouping by the propertyId doesn't give you the lowest price in the table.

I can't think of any way to do this in just one query. (aside from sub-queries you could use self join or set variable but both require a second query).

Comment: You already understand how the query functions -- it first finds the answer to one question, "what is the lowest rental price", and then uses that answer to find matching rows. It's not clear what else you want to know. It's two questions. How can a single query answer two questions? English lets you cram them together so they appear to be one question, but they're not.

Comment: @RossPresser - "How can a  single query answer two questions?" - easy `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM table  WHERE rentalprice IS NOT NULL ORDER BY rentalprice` - Not standard SQL but there is nothing impossible here.

Comment: You are quite correct, as is @sqlvogel. I should have thought more carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do it without a subquery.

```
SELECT t1.propertyId, t1.rentalprice
FROM tbl t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl t2
ON t2.rentalprice < t1.rentalprice
WHERE t2.rentalprice IS NULL;
```

I believe it has been claimed and is sometimes assumed that SQL subqueries are superfluous* in the language because they can always be replaced by joins. That *may* generally be the case. On the other hand, many new extensions have been added to standard SQL since SQL-99 and so many non-standard features exist in SQL DBMSs that I don't feel very confident. I'm not even confident that it could truly be proved either way, given the number of things that are non-deterministic or undefined in standard SQL and given the lack of a mathematical basis for many of its features. SQL is not relational and so relational algebra isn't much help in answering your question.

*Note this does not mean that derived tables, i.e. queries that appear in the FROM part of another query, are superfluous.